# Can a URL be opened with a limit on the number of lines returned using urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2

I know this might sound ridiculous, but is it possible to use `urllib2` to open a URL, so that only up to a set number of lines are returned?

The reason would be to reduce load time, especially for really large pages that I am working with. For example, this is my page:

```
1. <html>
2.  <head>
3.   <title>Hello!</title>
4.  </head>
5.  <body>
6.   <p>Hi there.</p>
7.  </body>
8. </html>
```

Say I were to open my page up to line 5, and then printing it once it has been read, it would give me:

```
1. <html>
2.  <head>
3.   <title>Hello!</title>
4.  </head>
5.  <body>
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

Sure is, you can use `readline()` instead of `read()`

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

lines = ""
for x in range(10):
        lines += response.readline()

print(lines)
```

Comment: I actually meant to only _open_ the page up until a certain line.

Comment: @user1447941: then what do you mean by *opening* up to a line?

Comment: @larsmans - I know it sounds stupid, but basically only downloading a set amount of lines from a site.

Comment: @user1447941: you mean *reading* up to a line. That's exactly what the answer does.

Comment: So you only want to allow your program to receive a certain number of lines of an HTTP response, and then what? Stop receiving the response after that? Unless you want to get pretty low-level, I think you're going to, at some level, receive the entire response when you make the request; this answer just controls how much of it you process. I'd recommend trying to make that work, as aborting the reception of data related to an HTTP response probably requires going down to the socket/SSL layers and mucking about, which I doubt you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your threshold and break out of the readlines loop.

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

read_until = 5    

lines = []
for line_number, line in enumerate(response.readlines()):
    if line_number >= read_until:
        break
    else:
        lines.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
from itertools import islice

list(islice(urlopen("http://www.python.org"), 5))
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'urlopen' is not defined`

Comment: @user1447941: `from urllib2 import urlopen`.